# Double labeling line problem using CSS for OSM data from Geoserver

Tags: geoserver, openstreetmap, wms, labeling, css

I had created a CSS for postgres planet_osm_line source on geoserver, for roads displaing
in client, using WMS.
CSS seted like:

```
/*.....*/

 /* @title Residential */
 [@scale < 20000] [highway = 'residential'] {
    stroke: #e2e1e1, #fefefe;
    label: [name];
    z-index: 0, 1;
    stroke-linecap: round;
    font-family: DejaVu Sans;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 10;
   label-follow-line: true;
     label-max-angle-delta: 90;
     label-max-displacement: 250;
     label-repeat: 300;
  }

 /* @title Tertiary */
 [@scale < 20000] [highway = 'tertiary'] {
    stroke: #e5e5a8, #f8f8ba;
    stroke-width: 10px, 8px;
    label: [name];
    color: #dadada;
    z-index: 2, 3;
    stroke-linecap: round;
    font-family: DejaVu Sans;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 10;
   label-follow-line: true;
     label-max-angle-delta: 90;
     label-max-displacement: 100;
     label-repeat: 100;
  }
 /*.....*/
```

But a unnormal artefact was detected: some line labels displays twice after n Zoom level:
[image]

red line shows double label, green normal label.
How to fix it using css or geoserver or OpenLayers configs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the `label-group` operator to make sure lines with the same name are treated as a single line. See the [manual](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/css/properties.html#text-symbology-labeling-part-1) for this and other options.

```
[@scale < 20000] [highway = 'residential'] {
    stroke: #e2e1e1, #fefefe;
    label: [name];
    z-index: 0, 1;
    stroke-linecap: round;
    font-family: DejaVu Sans;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 10;
    label-follow-line: true;
    label-max-angle-delta: 90;
    label-max-displacement: 250;
    label-group: true;
    label-repeat: 300;
  }
```